# Existential quantifier

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I've been doing a bit of independent research on existential quantification, and I was wondering if anyone could tell me if I have the hang of it. Here's a statement regarding the intermediate value theorem of calculus:

If $f$ is a function of $x$ that is continuous on the interval $[a,b]$, then $$\exists\left( p\in [a,b]\right)\,\left( f(p)\in [f(a),f(b)]\right)$$ is true.

If it helps, I typed this as
`If $f$ is a function of $x$ that is continuous on the interval $[a,b]$, then $$\exists\left( p\in [a,b]\right)\,\left( f(p)\in [f(a),f(b)]\right)$$ is true.`

Comment: Your statement is true but it is not the intermediate value theorem. Your statement verified by setting $p=a.$

Comment: The IVT says that, if $y\in[f(a),f(b)],$ then there exists $p\in[a,b]$ such that $f(p)=y.$

Comment: What's your question about existential quantification? It's hard to tell from just one example if you have the hang of it without more information.

Comment: Even if you replaced $[f(a),f(b)]$ by $(f(a),f(b))$ (to rule out $p = a$) you still wouldn't get something equivalent to the intermediate value theorem. Your expression would be true of continuous functions over the field of rational numbers but the rationals are not complete.

Answer (score -1):

If you are having trouble with existential quantifiers, there are just four rules that govern its usage in a mathematical proof (with each quantifier explicitly restricted to a set):

1. From $\exists x\in A: P(x)$, we can infer that $y\in A$ and $P(y)$ where $y$ is a free variable not previously used in that proof. (Existential specification or instantiation.)
2. (EDIT) From $y\in A$ and $P(y)$, we can infer that $\exists y\in A: P(y)$, or that $\exists x\in A: P(x)$ where $x$ is *not* a bound variable in $P(y)$, and where $P(x)$ is formed replacing some or all occurrences of $y$ in $P(y)$ with $x$. (Existential generalization)
3. From $\exists x\in A: P(x)$, we can infer that $\neg \forall x\in A:\neg P(x)$. (Changing quantifier, $\exists \to \forall$)
4. From $\forall x\in A:P(x)$, we can infer that $\neg\exists x\in A: \neg P(x)$. (Changing quantifier, $\forall \to \exists$)

where $A$ is a set and $P$ is a unary predicate.

Note that: $$\exists x\in A: P(x) \equiv \exists x: [x\in A \land P(x)]$$  $$\forall x\in A: P(x) \equiv \forall x: [x\in A \implies P(x)]$$

Avoid the construct:

$$\exists x: [x\in A \implies P(x)]$$

*Very* strange things can happen otherwise! (See "Drinker's Paradox" at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox) and at [my blog](http://dcproof.com/DrinkersParadox.html).)